# Difficulties in finding the radius of the disk in which power series of a function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

I am trying to find a function of asymptotic growth of the Fibonacci sequence, which's generating function is
$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}=\frac{1}{(1-\phi _-z)(1-\phi_+z)}
$$
with poles at
$
z_1=-\phi_- +2\pi ki
$
and
$
z_2=-\phi_++2\pi ki
$
$$
where \space \phi_±=\frac{1±\sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$
One of the necessary steps in finding the asymptotic growth of this sequence is to find the radius of the disk within which $f(z)$ is analytic, which would be easy if $f(z)$ had a pole at only one value of $z$ since radius would simply be the smallest magnitude of this pole in the imaginary plane.

But I am not sure what to do here since I have two poles giving me two different radii $r_1=|\phi_-|$ and $r_2=|\phi_+|$. Do I perhaps simply choose the radius with the smallest magnitude as I would if I had only one pole, or is there a more appropriate way to approach this problem?

Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the smallest magnitude of this pole"? A pole is a complex number, and a complex number has only one magnitude, not a bunch of magnitudes from which you may choose the smallest.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Correct me If I am wrong but wouldn't with $k$ increasing the magnitude of $z$ increase as well. Taking an example from my question where $z=\phi_-+2\pi ki$: 
 for $k=0$ $|z|=\sqrt{(\phi_-)^2 }$, for $k=1$ $|z|=\sqrt{(\phi_-)^2+(2\pi)^2}$. Therefore $z$ with smaller $k$ has smaller magnitude than same $z$ with the larger $k$.

Comment: $1/(a-bz)$ has **one** pole, at $z=a/b$, not an infinite string of poles depending on some $k$.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you understand that your $f(z)$ has two poles, and not two infinite families of poles.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I just realized where my misunderstanding came from. In the book I was learning poles from, they included only examples with $e^z$ constructing the pole, such as $\frac{1}{2-e^z}$, where through Euler's formula it does make sense for the function to have infinite family of poles, but that of course does not apply for my algebraic function. Thank you so much for your persistence in correcting me and I apologize for my stubbornness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius of convergence of a power series is the largest radius for which the series converges. In this case, the power series expansion of $f(z)$ is the Fibonacci sequence, so the radius of convergence of the Fibonacci sequence is the radius of convergence of the power series expansion of $f(z)$.

Since $f(z)$ has poles at $z_1=-\phi_- +2\pi ki$ and $z_2=-\phi_+ +2\pi ki$, the radius of convergence is the minimum of the magnitudes of these poles. This means that the radius of convergence is $r = \min(|\phi_-|, |\phi_+|) = |\phi_-| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$.

So the asymptotic growth of the Fibonacci sequence is governed by the singularity at $z=-\phi_-$, which has a magnitude of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. This means that the Fibonacci sequence grows asymptotically like $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you a lot.